# How to detect end-of-file when using "file-in" and "xml" nodes?

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am using Node-RED to extract data from an XML file. I am using the *file-in* node to read the file line-by-line and feed the output to an *xml* node to convert it into a Javascript object and pass it to a *function* node.

[image]

Given below sample XML, I would like to trigger a condition in *function* node when `</X12>` is encountered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<X12>
  <INTERCHANGE>
    <GROUP>
      <GS-FunctionalGroupHeader>
        <GS01-FunctionalIdentifierCode>GF</GS01-FunctionalIdentifierCode>
        <GS02-ApplicationSendersCode>CARRIERID</GS02-ApplicationSendersCode>
      </GS-FunctionalGroupHeader>
    </GROUP>
    <IEA-InterchangeControlTrailer>
      <IEA01-NumberOfIncludedFunctional>1</IEA01-NumberOfIncludedFunctional>
      <IEA02-InterchangeControlNumber>1504</IEA02-InterchangeControlNumber>
    </IEA-InterchangeControlTrailer>
  </INTERCHANGE>
</X12>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the file-in node in *a msg per line* mode each `msg` object should include a `msg.parts` section. This includes `msg.parts.index` which will include the line number from the file.

The `msg` for the last line should also include `msg.parts.count` which will hold the total number of lines in the file.

The xml node expect a whole XML document and will convert that into an equivalent JSON object, it has no concept of end of file.

Comment: I used the msg.parts.count to check for eof, thanks!